# How to create Holiday Function in PHP?

Tags: php, sql, oracle, function

I'm trying to make a function to generate holiday in PHP.
I've stored the holiday date in Oracle Table:

HOLIDAY
01-JAN-15
03-JAN-15
04-JAN-15
etc
My question is, how to make a function to get holiday date?
I mean, I need to find out that is_holiday('01-JAN-15') holiday is TRUE.

Here's my source code:

```html
<?php
include "config/connect.php";
function is_holiday($thedate)
{
 $sql = OCIParse($connect, "SELECT * FROM UF2T_HOLIDAY WHERE HOLIDAY = '".$thedate."'");
 ociexecute($sql);
 $result = oci_fetch_array($sql);

 if(!empty($result[0]))
 { 
  $holiday = "TRUE";
 }
 else
 {
  $holiday = "FALSE";
 }
 return $holiday;
}
echo is_holiday("08-JAN-15");
?>
```

This code doesn't work and always return FALSE.
What I'm supposed to do to make this code work?

**Additional information:**
I try to run it outside of a function, something like this :

```
<?php
include "config/connect.php";

    $thedate = '01-JAN-15';
    $sql = OCIParse($connect, "SELECT HOLIDAY FROM UF2T_HOLIDAY WHERE HOLIDAY = '".$thedate."'");
    ociexecute($sql);
    $result = oci_fetch_array($sql);

    if(!empty($result[0]))
    {   
        $holiday = "TRUE";
    }
    else
    {
        $holiday = "FALSE";
    }

echo $holiday;
?>
```

This code is work. So I think the problem is around the function. Any suggestion? Please help. Thanks in advance.
Sorry for my bad English. :D

Comment: I'd start with `print_r($result);`

Comment: Select HOLIDAY from UF2T_HOLIDAY WHERE HOLIDAY in('".$thedate."')

Comment: I'm sorry, it still doesn't work. :(

Comment: What is the datatype of column HOLIDAY - DATE or VARCHAR2 or ...?

Comment: Hi teo. the datatype is DATE. Something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, that problem is, that variable $connect is not available in your function. Try this:

```
function is_holiday($thedate, $connect)
```

and then call the function:

```
echo is_holiday("08-JAN-15", $connect);
```

Comment: Thanks, teo.
I think this is a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

That's becuase in PHP global variables by default are not visible in the functions. In your case the connection inside your function is a local variable which value is undefined. Change your function like this:

```php
function is_holiday($thedate)
{
    global $connect;
    $sql = OCIParse($connect, "SELECT * FROM UF2T_HOLIDAY WHERE HOLIDAY = '".$thedate."'");
    ociexecute($sql);
    ...
```

Comment: It is not good to use global variables - see my post for the solution.